# Problem in connecting my Arch linux to My raspberry Pi (raspbian)

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, dhcp, archlinux

I am having problems connecting my Arch to Raspberry Pi 3 via ethernet. I am having Realtek r8169. Though internet is working but when I connect it to my Raspberry Pi, it shows

```
wire connecting
```

The Ethernet and Raspberry Pi perfectly connects in windows.
Ethernet light blinks on both the ports

the command

> ip a

gives the following results

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:76:1c:b5:90:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::2e3b:cf60:a682:b685/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:e0:10:22:88:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 86215sec preferred_lft 86215sec
    inet6 fe80::31e8:7f66:951a:9c53/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Command

> ip r

gives

> default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp9s0 proto dhcp metric 600
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp9s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.7 metric 600

[image: Wired Connecting]: Like I said it keeps showing **Wired connecting**

and then

[image: Auth failure]

The cables are perfectly fine and works in my Windows 10.
In my Linux when I attach cable to router (for internet) then plug it into Arch, it shows **Wire Connected** but when I plug one ned to Pi and other to my Arch it shows **Wired connecting** and then **Auth Failure**. In short, ethernet is working as it is tested on windows (router and Pi) and Linux (router) but unable to get connected to Raspberry Pi (on Arch)

I suppose DHCP server is not the problem as when connecting to router for internet via ethernet, IP is assigned

Comment: are you connecting the pi directly to the computer running Arch? does it have DHCP server on the port you're connecting to?

Comment: Hello, do you like to give more details on a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create a direct ethernet connection, presuming the interface is up (if not `ip link set enp8s0 up`):<sup>1</sup>

```
ip addr add 10.0.42.1/24 dev enp8s0
ip route add 10.0.42.2 dev enp8s0 src 10.0.42.1
```

That's one side; the configuration is symmetrical, meaning doing the other side is exactly the same except you swap `42.1` for `42.2` and vice versa.  You don't have to use `10.0.42.X`, you can use anything from [a "private network" range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses).

You should then be able to `ping 10.0.42.2`.

This does not apply any port forwarding to share an internet connection (in the question it appears they already have that via wifi).

---

1. What "up" refers to in that context:

   ```
   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP [...]
                                 ^ This                               ^ NOT this.
   ```